# trying to find the word or bigram with the largest tf-idf using a output with sparseVector in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, tf-idf

I have been implementing the TF-IDF method described here with Python/Pyspark using feature ml, I have a set of 6 text documents, what the following code do is to get every bigram's tf-idf, but with a sparseVector inside the input, I am not able to find the bigram with the largest number of tf-idf for each book. In other words, what I want to do is to find the largest number of tf-idf, and use the number to find the corresponding word, Any helpful advice?

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import re
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer, NGram
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("wordCount")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory","1g")

def removePunctuation(text):
    return re.sub('[^a-z| ]','',text.strip().lower())

def wholeFile(x):
    name=x[0]
    name=name.split('_')[1].split('/')[2]
    words = re.sub('[^a-z0-9]+',' ',x[1].lower()).split()
    return [(word,name) for word in list(words)]


sc=SparkContext(conf = conf)
text=sc.wholeTextFiles("/cosc6339_s17/books-shortlist/*")
text = text.map(lambda x:(x[0].split('_')[1].split('/')
[2],removePunctuation(x[1])))

spark = SparkSession(sc)
hasattr(text, "toDF")
wordDataFrame=text.toDF(["title","book"])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="book", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(wordDataFrame)
ngram = NGram(n=2,inputCol="words", outputCol="ngrams")
ngramDataFrame = ngram.transform(wordsData)

hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="tf")
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(ngramDataFrame)


idf = IDF(inputCol="tf", outputCol="idf")
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)
```

part of my output is like this

```
 (u'30240', SparseVector(262144, {14: 0.3365, 509: 0.8473, 619: 0.5596, 1889: 
 0.8473, 2325: 0.1542, 2624: 0.8473, 2710: 0.5596, 2937: 1.2528, 3091: 1.2528, 
 3193: 1.2528, 3483: 1.2528, 3575: 1.2528, 3910: 1.2528, 3924: 0.6729, 4081: 
 0.6729, 4200: 0.0, 4378: 1.2528, 4774: 1.2528, 4783: 1.2528, 4868: 1.2528, 
 4869: 2.5055, 5213: 1.2528, 5232: 1.1192, 5381: 0.0, 5595: 0.8473, 5758: 
 1.2528, 5823: 1.2528, 6183: 5.5962, 6267: 1.2528, 6355: 0.8473, 6383: 1.2528, 
 6981: 0.3365, 7289: 1.2528, 8023: 1.2528, 8073: 0.8473, 8449: 0.0, 8733: 
 5.0111, 8804: 0.5596, 8854: 1.2528, 9001: 1.2528, 9129: 0.0, 9287: 1.2528, 
 9639: 0.0, 9988: 1.6946, 10409: 0.8473, 11104: 1.0094, 11501: 1.2528, 11951: 
 0.5596, 12247: 0.8473, 12312: 1.2528, 12399: 0.0, 12526: 1.2528, 12888: 
 1.2528, 12925: 0.8473, 13142: 0.6729,
```

Comment: The output I expect is a dataframe with three colums "title","bigram","idf"

Answer (score 1):

When using the HashingTF transformer your text input will be hashed with a hash function.
The problem with hashing is that it is not possible to retrieve the original input.

> it suffers from potential hash collisions, where different raw
>   features may become the same term after hashing. [see spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#tf-idf)

Therefore you can better use the [CountVectorizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#countvectorizer) instead of the hashing tf. The Countvectorizer counts the appearance of the terms (Term Frequency) without hashing the terms. The original vocabulary will be saved and can be extracted with:

`countVect = CountVectorizer(inputCol="words", outputCol="tf",  minDF=2.0)

model = countVect.fit(wordsData)
result = model.transform(wordsData)
model.vocabulary`

Then you can compute the idf with the CountVector.

```
idf = IDF(inputCol="tf", outputCol="idf")
idfModel = idf.fit(result)
rescaledData = idfModel.transform(result)
rescaledData.select("name", "features")
```

I am not sure if this is the best method but it works :) Change the dataframe to pandas en now select the features and combine it with the model vocabulary

```
rescaled_pd = rescaledData.toPandas()
rescaled_pd
```

Now select the top 100 by tfidf value or by count

```
tf_idf_per_word = pd.DataFrame({'tf_idf': inputrow['1_features'].toArray(), 'vocabulary': model_vocabulary}).sort_values('tf_idf', ascending = False)
 tf_idf_per_word[tf_idf_per_word.tf_idf>0.1]
 tf_idf_per_word = tf_idf_per_word[0:100]
```